# Advice on Android Activity performance

Tags: android, android-activity

I want your advice if the following way is the correct way(it works)

I have an activity and on the onResume() function I pull data from the database. I have an onClick event which deletes data if you require to.

My problem was how to refresh the screen with the new data so I decided to do this:

```
onPause();onResume();
```

This seemed to work(flawlessly I can say, I did not even notice a transition) and why wouldn't it, right? But then it occurred to me that if an Activity is paused it should not do any other actions(the onResume() call).

What do you think guys? Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: This is bad approach. You should not call any of `onXXX()` by hand. How you present your data from database?

Comment: why are you calling on methods manually. Those calls should be taken care by OS. whats wrong with populating the data after resuming the activity?

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com
I do a query with a cursor and then I pass the data to a ListView. When you long-press on an Item and you choose "Delete" I call the above(after handling data etc).

Also if I can't call onPause() how should I pause an Activity?

Comment: then to refresh your listview not the whole activity. also, why you need to pause activity by hand? you do not do that. System does as soon as user go away from your activity to another

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com I thought it destroyed the activity. Hm. I need to change some of my activities :P

Comment: I is absolutely not guaranteed. See the activity life cycle here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you have `refreshData()` which will be called from `onResume` and from whenever you want to refresh the data again?

Per rerquest from @webnetMobile I'm rephrasing the answer:

Do this: Can't you have `refreshData()` which will be called from `onResume` and from whenever you want to refresh the data again?

Comment: Alex, it's comment not answer.

Comment: @WebnetMobile You mean you didn't understand what changes are proposed by this my, well, text?

Comment: I did as you both suggested. Removed all onPause() calls and I created other functions to populate with data.

Seems better that way. Thanks dudes/ettes

Comment: I mean (and I do agree with others on that) that answer should be more in form "do this and that" instead of in form like yours. Solid recipe how to solve the issue. It is irrelevant if I do understand or not, but if OP and others looking for answer will get problem solved

Comment: @WebnetMobile I've rephrased the answer per your comment